# LAST_INSERT_ID() call inside trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following trigger on '`books`' table. 
The role of this trigger is to record entries in activity_owner and activity_log tables whenever any insert is made on books table.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `book_insert`;
CREATE TRIGGER book_insert AFTER INSERT ON books
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ownertable(`fk_acl_user`, `record_id`, `record_type`, `action`, `ip`)
    VALUES (NEW.`fk_acl_user`, NEW.`id_book`, 'book','insert', NEW.ip);
    SET @ACTIVITY_ID=LAST_INSERT_ID();

    INSERT INTO logtable(`fk_activity_owner`, `table_name`, `new_value`)
    VALUES (@ACTIVITY_ID, 'books', 
                CONCAT_WS('|', 
                    CONCAT_WS('', 'name~', NEW.`name`),
                    CONCAT_WS('', 'is_active~', NEW.`is_active`),
                    CONCAT_WS('', 'discount_amount_default~', NEW.`discount_amount_default`)
               )
            );
END;
```

The problem I am facing is that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` does not always return correct ID.
I have following questions:
a. What are the possible cases when I cant trust the result of `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.
b. Is there a better way to get the ID of last inserted record in ownertable.

please suggest.

Comment: If the `'insert into ownertable'` is *passed* then, the `'last_insert_id()'` should work. Failure possibilities are on a pooled shared database connection which is shared between requests. If another DML is executed in parallel, even with a `'microsecond'` difference, there is a chance that `'last_insert_id()'` too differs.

Comment: @ravinder so what practice should I follow to ensure that I always get the correct result from `last_insert_id()`. As my `@ACTIVITY_ID` does not always contain correct results.

Comment: Do you have any support result to claim your statement? If yes, try to run your code only when there is one request db connection and is not shared.

Comment: @ravinder what do you mean by a shared DB connection, can you let me know some resources from where I can get help on that. Also, please let me know how do I check whether my server is 'shared databse connection' or not?

Comment: I am not sure how you are sending queries to database server. If it is through some application, then check if it is using connection pooling. There is a possibility that connections from pooling are shared.

Comment: Nope each request is having its own private connection here Therefore, connections are not shared. Upon a request to server a new connection is created which holds up upon the request lifetime and is closed as soon as the request ends up.